# Variable inside sql query, to avoid multiple computations

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

How to avoid multiple calculations

I have this in a stored procedure(IBM DB2)

```
UPDATE my_table 
   SET field1 = my_func(fieldx, 1, 2), 
       field2 = my_func(fieldx, 1, 2) * fieldy
   WHERE my_key = 
 AND another_field < 0;
```

How can I avoid duplicate call to that function `my_func`?

Comment: Not sure as I've not touched db2, but could you not create a local variable and store the result in that? In Sql-Server you can just create a variable using DECLARE @x [SomeType], then set it using SELECT @x = blah or SET @x = blah - is the same thing not possible in db2?

Comment: Bit off topic, but I just googled db2 variables and came up with this page on setting a variable: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0001018.htm   ... can anyone tell me what the Syntax area means? What the hell are all those dashes?!! What's wrong with spaces? Who designed that diagram!?

Comment: [There's an article on how to read the syntax diagrams](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0006726.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two update statements . . .

```
UPDATE my_table 
    SET field1 = my_func(fieldx, 1, 2)
    WHERE my_key =   AND another_field < 0;

UPDATE my_table 
    SET field2 = field1 * fieldy
    WHERE my_key =   AND another_field < 0;
```

By the way, the following will not work as expected in DB2:

```
UPDATE my_table 
    SET field1 = my_func(fieldx, 1, 2),
        field2 = field1 * fieldy
    WHERE my_key =   AND another_field < 0;
```

This would use the old value for the second part of the set.

Comment: Running two update statements is likely to only be a significant gain if the function is non-deterministic and takes non-trivial time to run.  Otherwise, the cost of accessing the table twice will possibly 'cost' more.